# Use of making the base class polymorphic?

Tags: c++

I know the keyword `virtual` makes the base class polymorphic and if I create an object and call a `virtual function`, corresponding function will be called based on the run time allocation but why should I create an object with different types. I mean

```
Base *ptr = new Derived;

ptr->virtualfunction(); //calls the function which has implemented in Derived class.
```

If I create an object so that

```
Derived *ptr = new Derived; 
ptr->virtualfunction(); // which does the same without the need of making the function virtual.
```

Comment: check the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/  if you need a collection of these objects, or you don't know the exact subtype of the object (because it's depending on configuration, user input, etc..), you need polymorphism.

Comment: So your question is why there is a need for virtual methods at all?

Comment: _"but why should I create an object with different types"_ Both your examples create an object of the same type, the difference is the type of pointer you use to refer to it, but both examples create a `Derived`.

Answer (score 8):

Because you might want to store *objects of different types* together:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v;

v.push_back(make_unique(new DerivedA()));
v.push_back(make_unique(new DerivedB()));
v.push_back(make_unique(new DerivedC()));
```

Now, if you go over that `vector`:

```
for (auto& p : v) {
    p->foo();
}
```

It will call `foo()` of DerivedA, B, and C appropriately.

Comment: You should add that `std::make_unique` will be available starting with C++14. Also, the truly exception-safe way of calling it would be `std::make_unique<Foo>()` and not `std::make_unique(new Foo())`. Read here why: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm

Comment: and just to add to this - polymorphism comes at a price, and that price is a virtual method table (or vtable) to store the method pointers. Using the virtual keyword is way of telling the compiler "I want polymorphism, and I accept what this will cost"

Comment: @PaulManta That's precisely why I didn't prefix it with `std`. `make_unique` is, at least under the current standard, some sort of idiomatic way to spell it, and I used it just to shorten up the example. Your insights about C++14 are good, anyway.

Comment: @PaulDixon Everything comes with some price, however I don't think it makes sense to even mention that cost to beginners. Systems where vtables can really matter in terms of speed or size are scarce and developed on mostly by experienced developers (Even on hobbyist Raspberry Pi it won't really matter).

Comment: @PaulManta, `std::make_unique(new Foo())` isn't even valid, you do not pass the pointer to the function, it creates the object for you

Answer (score 2):

Let's go with a simple example : Let's say you have

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};
```

Now, let's say you want to be able to store in a vector (or any container) both Derived1 and Derived2 instances.
You have to use the base class in that case.

```
std::vector<Base*>
// or std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The need for polymorphism is the need of processing different data in the same manner. Rather than reimplementing over and over the same algorithm for dataset with different shapes, wouldn't it be much easier to have only one implementation of that algorithm, and parameterize it with different operators?

That's the essence of polymorphism. You start with an algorithm, establish the interface it must interact with, and then build implementations of that interface. In C++ the notion of interface is implicit in every classes. Any class exposes one interface (though it may support many interfaces through its ancestors), and its descendants implement it as well. By making certain methods virtuals, the descendants may override and adapt them to their own internal structures, without modifying how the object is manipulated from the outside.

So polymorphism is really that, values which may adopt different shapes, and the means to access and manipulate them uniformally. The key point in answering your question is perhaps that the algorithm *does not know* which implepentation it is manipulating. You provide a trivial example where the code knows that it works with an instance of `Derived`, and thus may call its methods directly. In generic code, or code refering to an interface (so to speak), that knowledge does not exist, which forces the code to rely on the base class methods (and requires the programmer to ensure that the classes he plans to use with that code are well defined - ie. virtual - where needed).

There are many useful applications of polymorphism, but they all derive from the above principle:

- heterogeneous dataset (as illustrated by other answers),
- [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) ( in which different implementations of the same interface may be swapped one for another at runtime),
- testing (and more specifically mocking, in which  classes which interact with a given class C are replaced by dummies which help test the correct behaviour of C),

to name a few. Note that compile time polymorphism (templates), and runtime polymorphism (`virtual` methods and inheritance) both achieve that goal, albeit in a different way, and with different pros and cons.